R: not able to find elements in html using rvest, or V8
I want to download, as a table, the text in the main table of the following website:
https://seia.sea.gob.cl/expediente/expedientesEvaluacion.php?modo=ficha&id_expediente=7673283
The table seems to be dynamically generated, as suggested by an answer to this---practically equivalent--- question. But trying to adapt the code, I haven't been able to get what I need.
I have not tried Selenium, because it asks me to install Java, but I don't have administrator permits on the computer I am using.
I tried using v8 following the answer to the question linked above, but, when running
ctx$eval(JS(js))

I get:
Error: ReferenceError: UbicaciónPlazos is not defined

I have no clue how to debug.
Perhaps this specific application will help others (and myself)

If you examine the network tab under your browser's developer's tool menu.
There is a file: "xhr_documentos.php" which contains the requested information.
url<- "https://seia.sea.gob.cl/expediente/xhr_documentos.php?id_expediente=7673283"

library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
page <- read_html(url)

table <- page %>% html_elements("table") %>% html_table()
table

Of course the "id_expediente=7673283" bit of the url address may change so this may not be a universal solution for constantly changing data.

Whats dplyr for? rvest does load the magritrr pipe function. Anyway still +1 for a direct solution. Just that you do not need the html_elements('table') part. read_html(url) %>%html_table() should be sufficient
